# there are two methods, want to call the second method after the completion of first method in angular 5

Tags: angular

Lets say I have two methods :

first: `this.a()`

second: `this.b()`

In *angular 5*, i want the ***execution of the second method to be completed first***, then only the next method should be executed.

How to make a asynchronous call for the same, i.e how to use promise to achieve it or is there any other way to achieve the same in angular 5?

Comment: any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What kind of methods do you have ? `Observable ?` `void ?` `any?`

Comment: yes , thats void

Comment: both are void methods

Comment: @billyjov ..FYI

Comment: @Aishwarya if both are void then what is the use of promises in those methods? Seems you have to rethink the design.

Comment: @Jai , is there any other way to do it. Because if i am calling both the methods together, i am unable to get the value of method 1). i need the value of method 1) to execute the method 2)

Comment: @Aishwarya Then in this case you have to change the return type to something else like promise. Then in that case you can call it when it resolves the promise.

Comment: If your methods are asynchronous, you can also sync them up by using **async-await** feature of javascript, check out this [link](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77)

Comment: You have stated two incompatible requirements - that b() completes before a(), and that you need the return value of a() to call b(). Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to have a return type other than `void`. In your case you can use `promise`:

```
a(): Promise<any>{
   return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
       // some async call
       let data = 123;
       //reject(new Error('Some error'));
       setTimeout(_ => resolve(data), 2000)
   });
}

b(): void{
   this.a().then(
       num => console.log(`${num} came from promise.`),
       err => console.log(err)
   );
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ykw8mq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @Aishwarya added a example at stackblitz.

Answer (score -2):

```
function1(variable).then(function() {
    function2(variable2);
})
```

Comment: this doesn't work as when i write my first method, and use then , its saying then is not to be used for void method

Comment: For example :- this.a().then is not allowed.

Comment: Yes. Since your return types are void. I didn't see that in the comments below. But you your first function should be returning some value as you mentioned you have to use that value in the second function right?

Comment: Yes. both the methods are void